# Which GARCH model to choose if both are showing same AIC/BIC and log-likelihood?

Tags: model-selection, aic, garch, bic

I am doing a GARCH model for returns under different error distributions using the R rugarch package. However, two models, under the generalised error distribution and the skewed generalised error distribution respectively, are performing the best. They have the exact same AIC/BIC and loglikelihood. Which one do I choose?

According to me, since the skewed version does not perform differently, I would choose the one under GED innovations. But I'm not sure. Can anyone help please?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Could it be that your skewed GED model estimates a skewness of 0, making it identical to the GED? Otherwise, if there is no difference, there is no statistical reason to prefer one or the other. I recommend tossing a coin. If you prefer the GED to the SGED, you have a prior belief which you did not formally factor into this model comparison.

Comment: The skewness is not 0 for SGED and is significant. Actually all the parameters of both models are significant. What do you mean by prior belief which I did not factor? Sorry for this inconvenience but I'm confused on how to explain this choice in my assignment.

Comment: The "belief" was just a comment because you wrote "I would choose". Thus, you seem to have a preference for one of the two approaches, which I would argue is an a priori belief, in a Bayesian sense. For your assignment: a typical argument would be that of parsimony. If both models have the same number of parameters (which they must if both loglik and AIC are identical), then I cannot think of a reason to prefer one over the other, except for ease of explanation in the methods sections of a paper.